# Detect that code run by RSpec, Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec, environment-variables

I would like to be able to know that my code is run under rspec or not. Is this possible?

The reason is that I am loading some error loggers that would be cluttered with deliberate errors (`expect{x}.to raise_error`) during testing.

I have looked at my `ENV` variable, and there is no (apparent) signs of a test environment variable.

Comment: Do you mean like the line-by-line coverage report provided by rcov?

Comment: @MarkThomas I'm not sure what you are asking. I am not using rcov, no. I have developed a monkey-patched thing that sniffs every exception generated and stores this for later analysis.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. Thought you wanted to know *which* code (i.e. which lines of code) were executed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add at the beginning of your `spec_helper.rb`:

```
ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'
```

Now you can check in your code whether the `RACK_ENV` is test or not.